# Performance of std::copy of portion of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, copy

I want to copy part of a vector to itself, e.g.

```
size_t offset; /* some offset */
std::vector<T> a = { /* blah blah blah */};
std::copy(a.begin() + offset, a.begin() + (offset*2), a.begin());
```

However, I'm concerned about the performance of this approach.  I'd like to have this boil down to a single `memmove` (or equivalent) when the types in question allow it, but still behave as one would expect when given a non-trivially-copyable type.

When the template type `T` is trivially copyable (in particular `int64_t` if it matters), does this result in one `memmove` of length `sizeof(T) * offset`, or `offset` distinct `memmove`s of length `sizeof(T)`?  I assume the later would give noticeably worse performance because it requires many separate memory reads.  Or should I just assume that caching will make the performance in these situations effectively equivalent for relatively small offsets (<100)?

In cases where the template type `T` is *not* trivially copyable, is it guaranteed to result in `offset` distinct calls to the copy assignment operator `T::operator=`, or will something stranger happen?

If `std::copy` doesn't yield the result I'm looking for, is there some alternative approach that would satisfy my performance constraints without just writing template-specializations of the copy code for all the types in question?

Edit: GCC 5.1.0, compiling with -O3

Comment: Which compiler? The standard does not mandate any optimization.

Comment: That's what C++ is supposed to be good at, so my bet is it could do it, *if* the STL implementation on your particular compiler is what it's cracked up to be. I would rather have a look at the generated assembly code to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no guarantees about how standard library functions are implemented, other than the guarantees which explicitly appear in the standard which cover:

- the observable effect of valid invocations, and
- space and time complexity (in this case: strictly linear in the number of objects to copy, assuming that copying an object is O(1)).

So that `std::copy` might or might not do the equivalent to `memmove`. It might do an element-by-element copy in a simple loop. Or it might unroll the loop. Or it might call `memmove`. Or it might find an even faster solution, based on the compiler's knowledge about the alignment of the datatypes, possibly using a vectorizing optimization.

<rant>Contrary to what seems to be popular opinion, the authors of the standard C++ library are not in a conspiracy to slow down your code, nor are they so incompetent that anyone with a couple of months' of coding experience could easily generated faster code. For particular use cases, you might be able to leverage your knowledge about the data being moved around to find a faster solution, but in general -- and particularly without profiling real code -- your best bet is to assume that the standard library authors are excellent coders dedicated to making your programmes as efficient as possible.
</rant>

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about standard, the answer is 'anything can happen'. Might do `memmove()`, might not. On the other hand, if the question is about a particular implementation, than you should not ask, but instead check your implementation.

On my implementation, it is a `memmove()` call.

By the way, it is hard to imagine implementation doing `offset` memory moves. It would be either single call to `memmove()`, or looped element-by-element copy. Calling `memmove()` just makes no sense.

Comment: "it is hard to imagine implementation doing `offset` memory moves. It would be ... or looped element-by-element copy" - it will do `offset` `memmove` calls if it does an element-by-element copy *and* each element copy is compiled to a `memmove` call.

Comment: @immibis, fair enough - but this would not be `std::copy`'s doing.